# Why do these diode connected JFETs not clamp my output?

Tags: diodes, over-voltage-protection

[image: JFET over voltage protection]

I've attached the LTspice image for some clarification, perhaps someone can see where I've gone wrong. I need to use JFETs to reduce the leakage currents (the outputs are going to an 18 bit ADC). Why are they not clamping the outputs to ~-0.2 - ~5.2V?

I've added some series resistance to the supply of the single ended to differential converter, which helped slightly, but as you can see, it's still not clipping.

Any ideas?

Comment: What leakage currents are you talking about?

Comment: Hi Andy - I'm referring to the reverse leakage current of (schottky) diodes

Comment: What schottky diodes? I see zero quantity of schottky diodes.

Comment: Indeed - I'm not using them due to their leakage currents. I'm using JFETs instead, as I pointed out (perhaps, not too clearly). To clarify:

I need to clamp the output of the circuit, usually this is done with diodes, specifically schottky due to their low forward voltage drop, usually lower than the internal ESD diodes of an IC. However, this is going to connect the to input of an 18 bit ADC, and I really don't want any leakage currents upsetting the reading - hence why I'm attempting to use JFETs, with their picoamp leakage currents.

Comment: Suppose that the (model) of ADC driver you're using has ideal outputs which can deliver an limitless amount of current, would a any clamp be able to limit the voltage? What components should you add to limit the current? Have you tried normal diodes instead of the JFETs to see if the clamping works? But my biggest question is: **WHY** would you need a low leakage current when the outputs can deliver all the current that is needed? **If** the diodes leak current, the ADA4941's outputs will simply deliver that current. My opinion: you're trying to solve a problem that does not exist.

Comment: *I really don't want any leakage currents upsetting the reading* But your **information** is not in the current but in the **voltage**. The ADA4941 is a single ended to differential converter which basically has **voltage outputs**. You're trying to clamp the voltage and **that** does affect the information. Looks to me like you have to re-think and re-design your system.

Comment: Forget about clamping if you are trying to protect the ADC inputs - just use series resistors to protect the ADC inputs. Your ADC data sheet will tell you what limit value of current is.

Comment: Unfortunately I've been handed the design to fix. I've been told that the inputs must be +/-5.5V, and they've already designed and built the circuit. I pointed out that under certain conditions, they're going to be exceeding the ADCs reference voltage. Since I can't say whether this will reduce reliability (it most likely will) they'd like a solution. If it was me, I would change the gain of the converter, but the resistors (2k and 1) are matched resistors on the same die to reduce temperature related gain drift. The simplest solution for me would be to replace the 2K with a 2.2K

Comment: The ADC states 130mA, but I'm not sure the affect of having resistors in series might be (hopefully no effects?)

Comment: Also: adding protection is fine if it is needed, if I was reviewing your design I would want an explanation **why** you need protection. In what situation would not having clamping / protection result in damage? If the ADC driver and the ADC run on the same supply voltage then usually the ADC's input voltage cannot go beyond the supply rails to usually protection isn't needed. And if there is a good reason to add the protection then I need proof that the protection doesn't affect performance.

Comment: Most the issues are due to whomever designed it before me. It's a bif of a nightmare. The ADC is 5V supply, single supply. The ADC driver is a +7 / -4V supply, and there's a buffer before that which is +/-12V. So, a total nightmare. I'm trying to straighten things out, but I'm really limited to what I can change. I think, though, I may just have to say that +/-5.5V input is not possible with the current design, and make the rest either 5V single supply, or +/-5V

Comment: Why have you shown the ADC driver to be +/-5.5 volts then?

Comment: Looks to me like, as I suggested, to take a step back and look at the **system design** yes even though your options of changing it are limited. Doing the "system design homework" helps you to pinpoint the issues and also helps in getting a better understanding. You can even build an idealized model in the simulator to easily try things out. The fact that you didn't realize that the information is actually in the voltage instead of the current is for me an indication that you really need to do the system level work first. At least, this is the way that I would attack this.

Comment: @Andyaka I have +/-5.5 for the ADC driver, as this is going to be my proposed solution. It occured to me that the outputs would then drive the ADC inputs higher that it's supplies, and so I then started thinking about how to protect against this. Bimpelrekkie I understand your point - I am aware the information is in the voltage (afterall, it's converting that voltage into a digital reading) I guess I just ran ahead of myself, wanting to use the JFETs I had heard about before. I believe another reason for them (other than leakage currents) is for speed (I guess reverse recovery time).

Comment: I guess the best solution is to have a buffer amp at the input of the single ended to differrential converter, with +/- 5V supply (rail to rail, of course). This would then saturate any higher voltages, and the ADC will only ever see 5V. Perhaps the buffer amp might require some protection diodes, though.

Comment: Clamp diodes need to have a resistance before them if they're going to clamp anything; you can't drop a voltage across an ideal wire.

Comment: I did add some series resistance, but no dice